# Terminal/iTerm2 issue: reverse-i-search trims off command

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, iterm

I've been having this issue since 10.9.

1. cd into a reasonably long path, e.g., `cd /Volumes/Storage/backup/long/path`
2. Enter a moderately long command, e.g., `curl -X GET http://localhost:8888`
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `curl`
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

The command displayed is shifted to far to the left and leaving whitespace to the right like so:

[image]

Is this a known bug or is it just me?

Comment: Reverse search is a function of the shell not the terminal. It would be worthwhile mentioning what shell you're using. `bash`? `zsh`? And to answer the second part of your question: it's not happening for me `zsh` 5.0.7 using the latest iTerm2 on 10.10.2. Edit starts at the end of the command as expected.

Comment: I'm using `bash` 3.2.53 and the latest iTerm2.

Comment: `bash` 3.2.57 is working as expected for me, here. It puts the cursor one character beyond the last character in the line every time.

Comment: @IanC. inspired me to switch to `zsh`, and I'm quite happy with it!

Comment: My dotfiles can help you get up and running fast with zsh: https://github.com/ianchesal/dotfiles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your `$PS1` - it's not properly escaped. You have to escape all non-printing characters with `\[` and `\]`. For example, if you have

```
PS1='\e[32m\u \W\e[0m $ '
```

you have to change it to

```
PS1='\[\e[32m\]\u \W\[\e[0m\] $ '
```

or your cursor will appear far to the right because your shell thinks your prompt is that long, and when it retypes the command it can't find it. Annoying, I know. In `zsh` you need to use `%{` and `%}` IIRC.

And while you're considering switching to another shell, I'd suggest [fish](http://fishshell.com). It's a bit more of a jump, but it keeps me sane.

Comment: My `PS1` is `PS1='\[\e[0;33m\]\u\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '` I can't quite seem to pick out what hasn't been escaped.

Comment: Note: it is unnecessary and undesirable to `export` shell variables. Interactive sub-shells will run the startup script and define the variable, and it is generally undesirable to have programs you run from the shell inherit shell-specific variables.

Comment: So glad I found this - I had a similar issue where reverse-search + edits was inserting the edits in the wrong place, and this fix was exactly the solution for that!

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate answer is: it's just you.

My `bash` is:

```
bash-3.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

And iTerm2 is the latest release and it behaves as expected: Ctrl-E during a reverse history search puts me at the end of the line, on character after the last character in the selected line.

It might be something in your `bash` configuration that's causing the problem. You can move aside your `~/.bash_profile` and ~/.bashrc` files and try Ctrl-R and Ctrl-E and see if things behave better. If they do, replace your customizations one at a time and see if you can spot the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `export TERM="xterm-color"` to `export TERM="xterm"` in my `.bash_profile` fixed the issue for me.